# Update a table at a specified time

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to update a table at specified time, for example at the end of month?

something like:

```
Update table1 set column1 = 1 where column2 = 2 (and give a date param when to update)
```

Comment: Put that statement in a script and schedule the script to run via cron or windows scheduler or what-have-you. Or [use oracle job scheduler](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25494_01/scheduse002.htm).

Comment: @JNevill Thank you very much for giving me the right key words to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick example:

```
 BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'Update_table1_monthly');
END;
/
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name             => 'Update_table1_monthly',
       job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
             job_action           =>  'begin
                                 Update table1 set column1 = 1 where column2 = 2;
                                 END;',
             start_date           => '27-NOV-18 12.00.00AM US/Pacific',
       repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1', 
       end_date             => '01-Jan-20 6.00.00AM US/Pacific',
       enabled              =>  TRUE,
       comments             => 'Update Table for first day of every month');
    END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the provided example. Right now i am using the gui of Oracle SQL Developer to schedule SQL Scripts as described under : [Schedule SQL Scripts Using SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/doc.41/e58244/GUID-01494B24-616D-4321-A862-C7790E60BECF.htm#DMRIG-GUID-01494B24-616D-4321-A862-C7790E60BECF). I will try your suggestion later.

Answer (score -1):

Create a job in SQL Agent. You can schedule it for any time you want.

Comment: This is an MS SQL Server utility which is no good for Oracle. For future reference please remember that the `[sq;]` tag refers to the generic SQL language, and is not short hand for MS SQL Server.